# Role/Previlige on a particular record in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, security-roles

I've three reports like

1. Report for Customer A
2. Report for customer B
3. Report for Customer C

Now I want to assign the role so that each customer will be able to see its own report. for example if customer A is logged in then only first report that is Report for Customer for A should be shown to him and respectively for other users.

I want your kind suggestion in this regards.

Comment: these reports are on same entity like case.

Comment: When you say customers are you actually referring to users or an entity like account?